# How to use underbrace in the following?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, braces

I was writing my project.

First notice the following:

[image]

When I use the `\underbrace`it becomes like...

[image]

Actually, I want the root sign like the above while using `\underbrace`

My code:

```
$\sqrt{(x-x^\prime)^2 + \underbrace{{(y-y^\prime)^2}}_{\geq 0} }\geq x$
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the `yhmath` package and use this code!

```
$\sqrt{(x-x')^2+ \smash[b]{\underbrace{(y-y')^2}_{\geq 0} }}\geq x$
```

[image]